# XMPP framework error: socket closed by remote peer

Tags: ios, sockets, networking, xmppframework

I am trying to connect to the ejabbered server with no SSL:

```
BOOL success;

if (![AppDelegate.xmppStream isConnected])
    success = [AppDelegate.xmppStream connectWithTimeout:XMPPStreamTimeoutNone error:&error];
```

but, the server returns the error

> socket closed by remote peer

In the:

```
- (void)xmppStreamDidDisconnect:(XMPPStream *)sender withError:(NSError *)error
```

I tried the following:

```
xmppPing = [XMPPPing new];
xmppPing.respondsToQueries = YES;
[xmppPing activate:xmppStream];
```

Also:

```
xmppAutoPing = [XMPPAutoPing new];
xmppAutoPing.pingInterval = 0.5;
[xmppAutoPing activate:xmppStream];
```

Also:

```
xmppStream.keepAliveInterval = 0.5;
```

But the error still exists. Is it something that I missed?

Log shows that connection accepted but returns the error:

> (<0.455.0>:ejabberd_listener:281) : (#Port<0.2757>) Accepted
>   connection {{111,111,111,111},55012} -> {{222,222,222,222},5222}